# .UpdateLayout() throwns an exception from RunWorkerCompleted method

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, exception, backgroundworker

I'm working on a app, where I'm adding items to a listview from a RunWorkerCompleted method using BackgroundWorker. From the RunWorkerCompleted method I'm adding ListViewItems, where I'm setting .Content and .Background.

However when setting the .Background property and calling the .UpdateLayout() method of the ListView class, I'm getting an exception: "Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.".

```
private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Something..cancelled");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Something..error " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                workLoad_listView.Items.Clear();
                workLoad_listView.Height = 23;
                foreach (Workload.workload element in Workload.Get())
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem item = new System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem();
                    item.Content = (string)element.name;
                    item.Background = element.brush; // if I outcomment this line, no exception is thrown!
                    workLoad_listView.Items.Add(item);
                }
                workLoad_listView.UpdateLayout(); //exception is thrown here!

                while (FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(workLoad_listView).ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    workLoad_listView.Height += 1;
                    workLoad_listView.UpdateLayout();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An exception was thrown!\n{0}", ex), "Exception caught", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

    }
```

This is the Workload class:

```
public static class Workload
{
    public struct workload
    {
        public string name;
        public System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush brush;
    }

    private static List<workload> workload_list = new List<workload>();

    public static void Add(string name, int colorNumber)
    {

        workload tmp_workload = new workload();

        tmp_workload.name = name;

        System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32(colorNumber);
        tmp_workload.brush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)color.R, (byte)color.G, (byte)color.B));

        workload_list.Add(tmp_workload);
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        workload_list.Clear();
    }

    public static List<workload> Get()
    {
        return workload_list;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` type is derived from `DependencyObject`. The `DependencyObject` type has thread-affinity; that is, it may be used only in the thread where it was created.

You haven't shown a complete code example; in particular, it's not clear from the example where your `Workload.Add()` method is being called. But given the error message, it seems extremely likely you are calling this from the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event handler. Of course, this handler is operating in a different thread from the UI thread where the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler is executed, and so the brush object is being created in a thread different from the one where you want to actually use it.

Basically: this is prohibited by the framework.

Again, without a complete code example, it's hard to know for sure what the best solution would be. However, based on the code shown here, it looks to me as though you should store the `System.Windows.Media.Color` value for the brush in your `workload` struct instead of a `Brush` value, and then create the `Brush` itself in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

I would also suggest changing the type names so that you don't have both a `Workload` class and a `workload` struct. Having two type names which are different only in the case of the first letter is potentially very confusing to others who may want to read the code (or to yourself, months later after you've forgotten how you implemented it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right about that the Workload.Add() method is being called from the BackgroundWorker's DoWork event handler. That did the trick for me :) - I've voted you for the best anwser! And thanks for your tip about not calling the workload struct the same as the Workload class - I understand that it could be confusing in the future ;)